# Vue 3 + Vue Router root page component fails render on app reinitialization

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have problem with router-view
My routes contains base route component as listed:

```
  { 
    path: "/", 
    component: Home,
    meta: { title: 'Main' }
  }
```

And that in App view:

```
<router-view v-slot="{ Component }" :key="route.path">
  <Suspense>
    <div style="height: 100%">
      <component :is="Component" />
    </div>
  </Suspense>
</router-view>
```

When i go to '/' route from another route or redirect all works correctly
But when I use F5 and app reload  Home component not rendering without any errors

Comment: I tested this out in an effort to help you out but had similar results. Suspense is still experimental and there are a number of open issues related to it on github at the moment: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+suspense